# Do something for every instance of a class

Tags: python, object

All right, so in this piece of code:

```
paint():
    print("So you want to paint your car?")
    color = input("What color will it be? ")
    carx.color = color                          #x = a car

class car:
    def __init__(self, tires, color, age):
        self.tires = tires
        self.color = color
        self.age = age

car1 = car(3, "Red", "1996")
car2 = car(4, "Blue", "2001")
car3 = car(4, "Black", "2006")

paint()
```

What I want to do is paint my three cars. As you can see, on line 4, I have written `carx`. I realize that's not how to do it, but whatever. I mean, that's what I'm asking, what should I write?

Also, I realize this could be done by returning a value in `paint()`, but is it possible to do it this way too?

EDIT: removed some unnecessary code.

Comment: You would need to keep a `list` of `car` or something like that.

Comment: Instead of having three variables `car1` through `car3`, consider having a single variable `cars`, which is a list containing all three car instances. Then you could do `cars[x].color`.

Comment: You _could_ create a list `cars` and append `self` to that list in `Car.__init__`. Whether you _should_ do this is another question. Why do you want this?

Comment: @Kevin Can you please explain that a little more thoroughly?

Comment: I was testing out a few things before, that's why the code is a little messy. The reason to why I want to do this is mostly just because I wonder if it's possible, how do I do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished most easily by changing you class structure a bit:

```
class Car: # class names are generally capitalized so that you can tell they're not local variable names.
    def __init__(self, tires, color, age):
        self.tires = tires
        self.color = color
        self.age = age

    def paint(self): # We make paint() a method of car
        print("So you want to paint your car?")
        color = input("What color will it be? ")
        self.color = color
```

Since paint is now a method of `car`, we can now do the following:

```
# First build a list of your cars
car1 = Car(3, "Red", "1996"),
car2 = Car(4, "Blue", "2001"),
car3 = Car(4, "Black", "2006")
cars = [car1, car2, car3]

# Then loop over it calling paint()
for car in cars:
    car.paint()

# I can can also still access them directly
car1.paint()

# And since Python uses references for everything, the version in the list will be updated as well
cars[0].color == car1.color # will be True
```

If however you want `paint()` to be a bit more generic and apply to many things that can be *paintable* and will always have an attribute called `color`, it would be even better to make a base-class instead:

```
class Paintable(object):
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color

    def paint(self):
        print('So you want to paint your {}?'.format(type(self).__name__)) # this will replace 'car' in your original print with whatever the class name  of the Paintable is
        self.color = input('What color will it be?')


# Now we make car inherit Paintable
class Car(Paintable):
    def __init__(self, tires, color, age):
        super(Car, self).__init__(color) # this sets the color via Paintable's constructor
        self.tires = tires
        self.age = age


 # And from here the rest is the same
```

This lets you easily define new things as being 'Paintable', should you need to.

If instead you're asking how you can call a single method and update all instances' `color` value to the *same* value, that's a different question and I'll update accordingly.

Comment: Forgot the `def` in front of `paint`. Also, `car` in the loop shadows the class name.

Comment: @tobias_k whopse. I'm so used to class names always being caps I didn't even notice :p

Comment: @aruisdante The second part seems to be interesting enough. What wonder, though, is, if all the values in list `cars` is named `car`, how do I access the values of a specific `car`?

Comment: @PhP  You access it via list-indexing, I.E. `cars[0]` gives you the `Car(3, "Red", "1996")` instance. I'll update with a version that maintains their independent names as well.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a concept of "all cars" in Python's type system. Your program essentially has a directed graph of names leading to objects:

```
main module
  "car"  --------------------------------------> \
  "car1" --> Car(3, "Red", "1996"),   class --->  } -> class "Car"
  "car2" --> Car(4, "Blue", "2001"),  class ---> /
  "car3" --> Car(4, "Black", "2006"), class --->/
```

The class "Car" does not know of any individual "Car" instance, nor do they know of each other. The traditional way to track a group would be to store them in a container such as a list:

```
mycars = [car1, car2, car3]
for car in mycars:
  car.color = "octarine"
```

It's also possible, though widely regarded as unsanitary, to inspect your own namespace to find the cars:

```
for name,obj in locals().items():
  if isinstance(obj,car):
    print("Found a car named %s, painted %s"%(name,obj.color))
```

Note however that this will find one of your cars twice, because `obj` is a local variable too.

Another way is to make the class automatically maintain a list of all cars, but that requires another interesting hack to prevent eternal cars: [weak references](https://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html).

```
import weakref
class car:
    all=weakref.WeakSet()
    def __init__(self, tires, color, age):
        self.tires = tires
        self.color = color
        self.age = age
        self.all.add(self)
def paintallcars(color):
    for carinstance in car.all:
        carinstance.color = color
```

Typically, the traditional list makes more sense, as you're tracking any number of cars in one or more contexts.

Comment: I thought about suggesting something similar (see my comment below the question), but without weakref... did not know this module. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you define your class with a variable non-specific to any one class like this:

```
class car:
    color = 'red'
    def __init__(self):
     ...
```

then all cars share that same attribute

```
car1 = car()
car2 = car()
car.color = 'yellow'

>>> print car1.color
yellow
>>> print car2.color
yellow
```

This is the difference between `color` and `self.color`. `self.color` is specific to each class, `color` is similar to a static class variable in C++, all car objects see the same one.

Comment: Actually, you're wrong. If you do ``car1.color = 'yellow'`` you're assigning to an instance-bound ``color`` attribute. It will not change the value of all cars, so ``car2.color`` will still be ``'red'``. You have to do ``car.color = 'yellow'`` to change the class attribute.

Comment: Also, the example in OP's question suggests that he probably does not want each car to have the same color...

Comment: @MikeP. The trick is remembering that there's nothing special about the word ``self`` (and in fact, you can call it anything, 'self' is just convention). It's simply the reference passed to the method when the '.' syntax is expanded from ``instance.method()`` to ``method(instance)``. So assigning to ``instance.attribute`` outside a class method is no different than assigning to ``self.attribute`` inside a class method :)

Comment: What you're describing is a class attribute, as opposed to an instance attribute. The car instances are not classes but objects of a particular class; note they have a `__class__` attribute pointing to `car`, but `car` does not have one.